# Dynamically change LOCALE_ID in Kendo UI for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

**How can I dynamically change LOCALE_ID?**
Currently I set it in app.module providers:

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "sl-SI" },
```

and load resources with require (as I found in [your documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/internationalization/#toc-systemjs-integrated-applications)):

```
import { load } from '@telerik/kendo-intl';
load(
    //supplemental data
    require("../cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
    require("../cldr-data/supplemental/weekData.json"),
    require("../cldr-data/supplemental/currencyData.json"),

    //locale data
    require("../cldr-data/main/sl/numbers.json"),
    require("../cldr-data/main/sl/currencies.json"),
    require("../cldr-data/main/sl/dateFields.json"),
    require("../cldr-data/main/sl/ca-gregorian.json"),
    require("../cldr-data/main/sl/timeZoneNames.json")
);
```

But I want to dynamically change it when user change language for example.

Changing translation with [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) is as simple as calling `translate.use('en');`.
How can I achieve same user experience for internationalization?
I suppose I need to dynamically load `cldr-data*.json` files, but then what?

Comment: LOCALE_ID is provided by the Angular DI, which is static. That being said, you cannot modify the locale ID dynamically out-of-the-box. The only feasible solution is to define a separate ngmodule, with different LOCALE_ID value.
Note this is Angular DI specific and applies to all static values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is currently work in progress for Kendo UI for Angular. [Current progress demo link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/internationalization/locale-changes/).

[Here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1455) is also link to the issue on GitHub.